# How to send an email upon successful BTEQ job completion?

Tags: bash, email, teradata

I am using crontab to schedule BTEQ scripts (like the one below). I would like to send an email notifying the successful completion/failure of a job. Is it possible?

```
#!/bin/bash

bteqSYSTEM="VTDSSBP"
bteqUSER="#######"
bteqPWD="##########"

bteq <<- BTEQSCRIPT 1> /DATA/home/pverma3/Daily_Jobs/Shell_Scripts/Customer_Details_TD.log
        .LOGON ${bteqSYSTEM}/${bteqUSER},${bteqPWD}
        .RUN FILE=/DATA/home/pverma3/Daily_Jobs/TD_Codes/Customer_Details.sql;
        .LOGOFF
        .QUIT
BTEQSCRIPT
```

I don't think we can do from the SQL code it is directing to, so I believe I need to add some code lines here in the script which will fetch the results from the Teradata SQL run and send it to the email. Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on your linux server. Assuming it's set up to email you can use the `mail` command or you can install a more robust client like `mutt`. This is more of a shell/bash question then it is Teradata.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. Can you please help me with the syntax. I googled and it is in the lines of .if errorcode <> 0 then mail -s "Fail" else -s "Pass"  from "myemailid@whereiwork.com"  to "myemailid@whereiwork.com". But I have no experience in bash scripting so kind of struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can capture the return code back in the shell (once BTEQ exits) and then send an email based on that return code. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

bteqSYSTEM="VTDSSBP"
bteqUSER="#######"
bteqPWD="##########"

bteq <<- BTEQSCRIPT 1> /DATA/home/pverma3/Daily_Jobs/Shell_Scripts/Customer_Details_TD.log
        .LOGON ${bteqSYSTEM}/${bteqUSER},${bteqPWD}
        .RUN FILE=/DATA/home/pverma3/Daily_Jobs/TD_Codes/Customer_Details.sql;
        .LOGOFF
        .QUIT
BTEQSCRIPT

rcode=$?
if [[ $rcode != 0 ]]; then
    mail -s "Fail" myemailid@whereiwork.com
else 
    mail -s "Pass" myemailid@whereiwork.com
fi
```